# Can't decompress a file I compressed using BZip2

Tags: vb.net, compression, arrays, sharpziplib

I have a program that compresses a file using BZip2 then saves it to a new file.

```
Public Sub Create(ByVal outPathname As String, ByVal filePath As String)
    Dim msCompressed As New MemoryStream()
    Dim zosCompressed As New BZip2OutputStream(msCompressed)
    Dim fileInput As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
    Dim buffer As Byte() = GetStreamAsByteArray(fileInput)
    zosCompressed.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    zosCompressed.Flush()
    zosCompressed.Close()
    buffer = msCompressed.ToArray()
    Dim FileOutput As New FileStream(outPathname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    FileOutput.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.LongLength)
    FileOutput.Flush()
    FileOutput.Close()
End Sub
```

But I can't seem to figure out why I can't decompress the file it created. Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my decompressor here? (It's in a separate program than the compressor.)

```
Public Sub Extract(ByVal archiveFilenameIn As String, ByVal outFolder As String)
    Dim fileInput As New FileStream(archiveFilenameIn, FileMode.Open)
    Dim msUncompressed As New MemoryStream(GetStreamAsByteArray(fileInput))
    Dim zosDecompressed As New BZip2InputStream(msUncompressed)
    Dim buffer As Byte() = GetStreamAsByteArray(fileInput)
    zosDecompressed.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length())
    buffer = msUncompressed.ToArray()
    Dim FileOutput As New FileStream(outFolder & "\temporary.bmp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    FileOutput.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.LongLength)
    FileOutput.Flush()
    FileOutput.Close()
    zosDecompressed.Close()
    msUncompressed.Close()
    fileInput.Close()
End Sub
```

EDIT: I'm also using a function for converting a stream to a byte array here:

```
Private Function GetStreamAsByteArray(ByVal stream As System.IO.Stream) As Byte()
    Dim streamLength As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length)
    Dim fileData As Byte() = New Byte(streamLength) {}

    ' Read the file into a byte array
    stream.Read(fileData, 0, streamLength)
    stream.Close()

    Return fileData
End Function
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Finalize BZip2OutputStream before using written data. That was helpfull for me.

```
zosCompressed.Finalize();
buffer = msCompressed.ToArray();
```

[BZip2OutputStream usage example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6834/MemoryStream-Compression).

Comment: The usefulness of this is limited, as calling `Finalize()` closes the underlying memory stream and totally defeats the purpose of having a compressed memory stream.